# Why is sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score so slow for sparse matrix input?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, k-means

I'm trying to cluster a bunch of 34-element vectors (~200,000) using `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` and assess the results using `sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score`; this is the subject of the question [How to use silhouette score in k-means clustering from sklearn library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138686/how-to-use-silhouette-score-in-k-means-clustering-from-sklearn-library), but with the following difference:  For that question, the data came from a DataFrame, whereas the vectors for my problem are represented by the rows of a CSR matrix.  Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
sparse_vectors = sp.coo_matrix(...).tocsr()
n_clusters = 256
kmeans_clusterer = MiniBatchKMeans( n_clusters = n_clusters )
cluster_labels = kmeans_clusterer.fit_predict( sparse_vectors )
print( "done with KMeans, cluster_labels.shape", cluster_labels.shape, file = sys.stderr )
clustering_score = skl.metrics.silhouette_score( sparse_vectors, cluster_labels, metric = "euclidean" )
print( "n_clusters", n_clusters, "clustering_score", clustering_score, file = sys.stderr )
```

What I observe from the first `print` statement is that the clustering takes under a second, whereas I have not yet had enough patience to wait for the second `print` statement.

Is there something I can do to speed up the call to `silhouette_score`, or alternatively, is there a faster way to evaluate the quality of the clustering, so that I can decide what value to use for `n_clusters`?

Comment: I think the answer to "is there a faster way?" is >yes<.   I implemented a very simple Python function to compute the RMS average intracluster distance (distance from each vector to the center of the cluster it belongs to) and it runs in a few seconds.

Comment: `silhouette_score`'s `kwds` get passed to the distance function, so pass `n_jobs=-1` to speed it up.

Comment: @MarkLavin could you post your alternative?